# I don't understand the width field in pprint in python

Tags: python, width, concept, pprint

I don't understand this concept clearly. 
Could somebody give me some examples to demonstrate the concept for width in pprint in python?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically it tries to limit your output to a specific width.

Here's an example:

```
import pprint
stuff = ['spam', 'eggs', 'lumberjack', 'knights', 'ni']
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(width=80)
pp.pprint(stuff)
```

result is:

```
['spam', 'eggs', 'lumberjack', 'knights', 'ni']
```

but if you do the same thing but change the width(say to 10):

```
import pprint
stuff = ['spam', 'eggs', 'lumberjack', 'knights', 'ni']
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(width=10)
pp.pprint(stuff)
```

you get:

```
['spam',
 'eggs',
 'lumberjack',
 'knights',
 'ni']
```

This is a modified example from the python docs ( http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html ).  For things like this, I find it easier to just open the python interrupter and play around and see how the commands react to what you enter.